# How to link a .o file in a codeBlocks project?

Tags: c++, linker, codeblocks

I am trying without success to link a **.o file** to my codeBlocks project. I tried to go to: **Projects -> Build Options -> Linker Settings** 
But i don t know what to do there exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the object file in the same way as local library:

**Project build options** -> **Linker settings** -> **Link Libraries** -> **Add**

Add the absolute filename, e.g. `/path/to/myFile.o`. Use the **[...]** button to the right of the **Add library** dialog to locate the file.

Comment: I tried to do it, but it is not working. I still get this error by compiling: "can not find myFile.o" .

Comment: CodeBlocks was asking me if i wanted to use the relative path, i was telling him yes, that's  why it was not working. Now i say no,and  it writes the path in the Add Library dialog and works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @stfsngue You're right. That seems to be a small C::B bug. I've corrected the answer.